# Getters Setters Autoproperty issue

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Having an issue with autoproperty. Here's snippet from my class:

```
 class Car
{
    string brand;
    string model;
    Engine CarEngine {get; set;}
```

Now the class Engine:

```
class Engine
{
    double FuelCap { get; }
    double fuelCapDefault = 50;
    double FuelCount { get; set;}
    double engineCap;
```

I created an object with constructor:

```
  public Car(string brand, string model, double engineCap, double FuelCount, double FuelCap)
    {
        this.brand = brand;
        this.model = model;
        this.CarEngine = new Engine(engineCap, FuelCount, FuelCap);

    }
```

and the constructor for Engine:

```
public Engine(double engineCap, double FuelCount, double FuelCap)
    {
        this.engineCap = engineCap;
        this.FuelCount = FuelCount;
        this.FuelCap = FuelCap;
    }
```

I've created an object with:

```
 Car car = new Car(x, y, z, a, b);
```

Now to the main point, finally:

I'm trying to access car.CarEngine.FuelCount in my Main Program to get the value, but Visual doesn't even suggest me the CarEngine. I'm new to the whole autoproperty stuff.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: you forgot to make `CarEngine` public. "`public Engine CarEngine {get; set;}`", same for `FuelCount`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain The whole point of me using getters/setters was not to make it public :(

Comment: Getters and setters use the parent scope by default, if you want a public getter and a private setter do `public Engine CarEngine {get; private set;}`

Comment: @user3653415 - "the whole point was not to make it public" - then you don't understand properties. The automatic *variable* behind the autoproperty is not public, but the property needs to be public otherwise it serves no purpose in your code. If you want to access the property from outside `Car`, the property has to be something other than private.

Answer (score 5):

All the properties that you have declared doesn't have any `modifier`, so by default they are `private`. This means that they can only be accessed within the declaring class.

Mark them `public` will solve the problem.

> All types and type members have an accessibility level, which controls whether they can be used from other code in your assembly or other assemblies. You can use the following access modifiers to specify the accessibility of a type or member when you declare it:
>
> `public`
>   The type or member can be accessed by any other code in the same assembly or another assembly that references it.
>
> `private`
>   The type or member can be accessed only by code in the same class or struct.

For the full list see [Access Modifiers (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)